# Why w3 validator says onClick is not valid?

Tags: onclick, w3c-validation

w3 validator gives me this error

```
there is no attribute "onClick"
```

I can't see what is making my code invalid.

```
<a href="#" onClick="return BookmarkApp.addBookmark(this)"><img alt="" src="./favorites-intro.jpg" /></a>
```

suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you change it to lower case `onclick`, the error goes away. Like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return BookmarkApp.addBookmark(this)"><img alt="" src="./favorites-intro.jpg" /></a>
```

Comment: youre right. i thought all lowercase was only for html5.. anyway, the error is gone. thank you!

Comment: If you're validating against XHTML it also must be lower case.  HTML 4 doesn't require this same restriction.